# Why does my PSU turn off after connecting 12 V to -12 V?

Tags: power-supply

I first turn on a desktop ATX power supply by jumping the PSU ON to ground. The fan comes on as expected. However, when I connect the 12 V to -12 V or even 12 V to ground, the PSU just shuts off. Why?

[image]

Comment: What were you expecting it to do?

Comment: @DoxyLover Send my 12-24 volts to the bulb while the PSU stays on

Comment: @Privvet Now that is confusing. You say you were shorting 12V to GND. Now you say you are connecting to a bulb. Both cannot be true at the same time. Please draw what you are doing and how the connections look like.

Comment: @DoxyLover I have edited in a rough diagram of this circuit. Pins listed are the only pins in use. That's how you're supposed to draw switches, right?

Comment: Are you shorting the + and - 12V or connecting a load between them? That diagram is not particularly legible, so it is hard to tell. Maybe annotate the diagram, or use standard symbols? Is that a light bulb, and F+ and F- are the connections to the filament? Also, fix your textual description, as you state "when I connect the 12v to -12 or even 12v to ground"... which implies shorting, and which also contradicts the diagram.

Comment: Which lamp has 3 terminals? Why does it need +12V, -12V and ground? Which lamp is it and how have you really connected it? Is it a 12V lamp, how many watts of power or amps of current it takes?

Comment: Check for a minimum load required on 3.3/5 V. Try connecting *one* filament first and only then "PSU ON" - if this fails, retry with 5 V. Don't count on -12 V to supply more power than +12 V at any time unless the PSU specs explicitly says so. See also: [ATX PSU turns off under heavy 12V load, unless increased gradually](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/527507/274544)

Comment: @Greenonline I am connecting a load between them. It is an X-Ray tube. The bottom of the tube is even labeled the way it is in my diagram https://imgur.com/a/PcuARr0. Sorry, I assumed that I was essentially connecting 12 to -12 when I connect 12v to F+ and F- to -12v. Justme, yes I am sure, because simply touching the wires cuts the PSU off. I'm not sure of the watts or amps it takes. On the website, it was listed as 
Peak anode 77 A
AVG anode 6.4 A
Surge 770 A
Heater 21 A

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add *all* of that additional info there (including uploading the photo (not the link) of the X-ray tube), and not in the comments. The comments section is intended for clarifications to be asked to be added to the question - that way all of the info is in just one spot and not spread throughout the comments. Thanks. Also, only one person can be addressed per comment (using the @ symbol), so Justme may not see your reply - although, again, it is best to put that info in the question and not the comment.

Comment: OK, so it is now an X-Ray tube instead of a lamp. Why do you even think that it can be powered with +12V and -12V and GND from a computer supply, if you don't know what voltages it works with? Also if it can, please understand that X-Ray emitters are dangerous and operating them may require a permit and you might need to have a license to prove you can operate an X-Ray device safely.

Comment: @greybeard On an ATX PSU, I wouldn't expect the -12V rail to handle more than an Amp. A difference of 2 orders of magnitude compared to +12V is not unusual (just a random pick from my stash: +12V @ 57A, -12V @ 0.5A).

Answer (score 6):

In the comments you are stating that you are trying to power an X-Ray tube.  One that takes serious amounts of power.  You are powering it with an utterly unsuitable power supply, have no solid grasp about electricity, are trying to power a device more likely than not intended for very short bursts of operation.  You have no clue what you are doing while trying to operate a device with the potential to expose you to lethal amounts of inconspicuous radiation.

Yes, according to the rules of this site, this is not an answer but a comment.  But any answer significantly differing from "stop this while you can" would be reckless.

Answer (score 0):

You are short circuiting the output so the power supply turns itself off to prevent further damage.

Don't connect wires together that are not supposed to be connected together.

Comment: If you aren't meant to close the circuit by leading the 12v to gnd or -12v once you're done with it, then how do I close it while keeping my power? I should have caveated that I am fairly new to messing with PSU's.

Comment: You don't connect +12V to GND or +12V to -12V when done. You just connect them to a load or don't.